# Select from array by column by 1d-array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have two `numpy` arrays:

```
array_1.shape = (10000,15)
array_2.shape = (435,)
```

I want to select a sub array from `array_1` where the first column (`array_1[:,0]`) is equal to one of elements of `array_2`. Something like `array_1[array_1[:,0]==array_2]`.

Comment: array_1[array_1[:,0]==array_2], and it not the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since those are numpy arrays, you can use `np.in1d` to find indices of elements of array_1[:, 0] in array_2, then index array_1 with this result.

`inArray2 = np.in1d(array_1[:, 0], array_2)` gives a boolean array of length `array_1.shape[0]`, with the value at index i equal to **True** if `array_1[i, 0]` is in array_2, **False** otherwise.

So `array_1[inArray2]` gives the expected output.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I am lookin for, that will return elements from array_1 which have as indexes the elements of array_2